# Librosa libray [Python] resample function on Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, librosa, libsndfile

I am using librosa to resample the audio data, like below:

```
import librosa
filename = "/home/.../example.mp3"
audio, samplerate = librosa.load(filename) # samplerate = 48000
target_samplerate = 24000
new_audio = librosa.resample(audio,samplerate ,target_samplerate ,res_type='sinc_fastest')
```

This code works in my local linux system. However, when I deploy such code to the Azure function, it outputs Error: `OSError: sndfile library not found Stack`

The reason should be the `librosa.resample` function needs  two C build Libs: **Libsndfile** and **Libsamplerate**. I can install them on my **local** linux system:

**For Libsndfile:**

```
sudo apt-get libsndfile1
sudo apt-get libsndfile-dev
```

**For Libsamplerate:**
I first download the file from github: https://github.com/libsndfile/libsamplerate Then just follow the install instruction:

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

**But how to install these two Libs on Azure function?** Please give me some help! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Azure Function on Linux runs in a default container. So Installing via `apt-get install libsndfile1 & apt-get install libsndfile-dev` in the Function host would have no effect on what's inside the container.
For such scenario, you should consider [Creating function using a custom container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-python).

- You can use a Function base image for python from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker#python)
- In the docker file provided above, you would see several `apt-get` installation depending on what image you choose. Just add your required dependency (`libsndfile1,libsndfile-dev` in this case).
- Build and deploy your function referring the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-python).

Note: Custom image is not supported in Consumption plan. It would need Premium plan or a Dedicated (App Service) plan.